# Stream gz file to a char array

Tags: c++, mfc, stream, gzip

Language: C++ (MFC) with VS2010

I am trying to stream a .gz file so that I can convert it to an array. I will then send this array to the server. I want the whole .gz file not only the contents, because the server requires a .gz file.

Any suggestions on how I could go about this? I've tried fopen(), but it won't work.

Here are my other attempts:

```
// common variables
ifstream fGZStream;
char * strData;
```

1) Using ifstream:

```
fGZStream.open(gz_filename, ifstream::binary);
strData = new char[nFileSize];                 //assume nFileSize if already ok
fGZStream.read(strData, nFileSize);
fGZStream.close();
```

2) Using CFile:

```
CFile fGZFile;
file.Open(gz_filename, CFile::modeRead);
strData = new char[nFileSize];                 //assume nFileSize if already ok
file.Read(strData, nFileSize);                 
file.Close();
```

3) Using fstream and filebuf:

```
filebuf* fGZBuffer;
fGZStream.open(gz_filename, ifstream::binary);
strData = new char[nFileSize];                 //assume nFileSize if already ok
fGZBuffer->sgetn(strData, nFileSize);            
fGZStream.close();
```

In all these attempts, strData always ends up being equal to ".".

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is nFileSize? What do you see if you actually check the return values from your function calls?

Comment: nFileSize is the size of the opened file (.gz file). For the file I'm testing now, it is 79.

Comment: @JasonD thank you for your attention. nFileSize is the size of the opened file (.gz file). For the file I'm testing now, it is 79. ifstrea::open() returns void. read functions return 79 (equal to the nFileSize).

Comment: How are you checking the contents of strData? A binary file will not be meaningful as a printed string, what does it look like as hex?

Comment: Hi @JasonD. I check the value of strData by adding it to my watch list while debugging. The value is displayed as 0x01adb298 ".".

Comment: That's not particularly useful - you're viewing it as a string. You need to look at the binary contents of your allocated array. For example, open a memory view.